# Cheking if a value exists in a database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database in **mysqli** like this:

```
|--------------|-------Users-----------|---------------|
|id------------|------username---------|----------email|
|1-------------|--------test-----------|-test@gmail.com|
```

**php:**

```
class User{
    public static function exists($dbType="",$type=""){
        $result = "SELECT * FROM Users  WHERE ".$dbType."='{$type}'";
        return (mysqli_fetch_array($result) == 1) ? 'NO' : 'YES';
    }
}
```

I check it like this:

```
echo "First: " . User::exists("username", "testUsername") ." | ". User::exists("email", "test@gmail.com") . "</br>";
```

but the problem is it only returns "NO" even though testUsername doesn't exists in the database.

Comment: You didn't execute the query. First execute the query using `mysqli_query()` and then use `mysqli_num_rows()` function to check how many rows it returned.

Comment: You should use SELECT COUNT (*). This would be more performant. You don't need to select all fields of the table just to check which COUNT you have.

Answer (score -1):

the result of mysqli_fetch_array($result) is an array. If you want to know if there was a result from the database you should try to count the size of the array.

try this:

```
class User{
    public static function exists($dbType="",$type=""){
         $query= "SELECT * FROM Users  WHERE ".$dbType."='{$type}'";
         $result = mysqli_query($query);
         return (sizeof(mysqli_fetch_array($result)) == 1) ? 'NO' : 'YES';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `mysqli_query()` is wrong. In the procedural way it receives at least two arguments, first is the connection handler, which OP didn't mention in the question and second is the query. Please read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Answer (score -1):

```
public static function exists($dbType="",$type=""){ 
    $query= "SELECT * FROM Users  WHERE ".$dbType."='{$type}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);

    return (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) ? 'NO' : 'YES';
}
```

Thanks to  Rajdeep Paul